# segmentation fault process returned 139 (0x8b)

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm new to Linux & codeblocks. When building the code below i receive this error:

> "segmentation fault process returned 139 (0x8b)"

I know it has something to do with memory but I cannot find the problem. While compiling the files with a Makefile or separately in the terminal I don't receive any errors.

The `main` receives 2 arguments `(argv) ComputersInNet.txt - > argv[1] Simulation.txt -> argv[2]`

AND I cannot figure out how I add these files to the project using codeblocks, ALSO in Windows (Visual Basic) the codes works perfectly.

I couldn't paste the codes correctly (5 files: 2 .h and 3 .cpp) you can download them from the link below, including both txt files I use as arguments.

http://depositfiles.com/files/cv2bwmz74

Comment: Well, very often a segfault in one system runs fine in another because the consequences of memory overruns depend on what's in the memory you are overrunning, and that's platform dependent, so I wouldn't worry about why it works on one and not another.  That said, have you checked all your pointers to make sure they are initialized and not NULL?

Comment: Post up the code here instead of making us download and unrar it;)

Comment: Yeah, I just visited the link, saw the download setup and balked.

Comment: Have you tried run it under gdb or valgrind?

Comment: Do you get the fault "when building the code" as you state (in which case the arguments to `main()` (and your code) are irrelevant, as it's an issue with your Codeblocks and/or compiler or other utilities, or when you run the program after building it, in which case your code and the contents of the arguments are relevant...?

Comment: You're saying it faults "when building the code" it's not clear if the compiler is throwing the seg fault or your app.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replays!!

Sorry about no pasting the code i've tried that but it comes out not good.

i've rechcked and every pointer that was initialized to 'NULL'
was changed to just - <type>* X;
no initialization to NULL.

But still getting the same error

In the build log i get this line :"process terminated with status 0 (minutes 6 seconds)

so i guess the build part goes well, but in the run part that where it fails

Comment: Also when compiling the program manually in the terminal, i don't any error, another sigh that is fails in the run part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet problem is occured,  subroutine `Create_PC_List()` is invoked from `main()` to create a list of computers.

```
void Router :: Create_PC_List (char *fname) //Reads from file & creates list of computers
{
char C;
char* IPAD=NULL;
FILE* fp;
FILE* msg;
int counter=0;
fp = fopen (fname,"r"); //Reading from Argv parameter file - list of computers in the network
if(fp == NULL)
        cout << "Opening file failed: %s\n" << strerror(errno) << endl;
msg = fopen (fname, "r"); //Reading from Argv parameter file - list of computers in the network
    while((C=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) //Running trougth the file
{
    ...
```

Output:

```
Opening file failed: No such file or directory
followed  by segmentation fault.
```

We could see `fopen()` failed with error `"No such file or directory"`. Therefore, you need find a way to add three text files to Code Blocks an made available for `fopen()`.

Secondly reason for the segmentation fault is fp provided to `getc()` is a `FILE *` pointer containing a **NULL** address that is not a valid **FILE** object.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay ! iv'e tried adding these files as i mentioned before, but i doubt the i'm doing it right. this is where i've written the file names in the codeblocks:

http://postimage.org/image/9kauxc42b/

But i'm still getting the same Segmentation error. Any advice ???

Comment: @DavidFaiz I think these .txt's files should be placed in Project menu -> Program Arguments and not in Host Application. Check with CB help Forum.

Comment: in this link u can see that i have no area to write the file names
 postimage.org/image/9kauxc42b

Comment: A couple comments on the code fragment - 1) you are outputting "Opening file failed..." regardless of whether the `fopen()` failed or not - there's no `if` statement there. 2) The second `fopen()` could possibly fail as well, but you're never checking it. 3) If the first `fopen()` did in fact fail, you're still trying to call `fgetc()` with the result, which is at best undefined behavior, and could quite possibly be the source of the segmentation fault, depending your compiler/library/system versions.

Comment: @twalberg Yes I agree completely with you. I missed placing correct statements in my answer. Ideally we should return; when fopen() return NULL. At the time of debugging I remember it did work and didn't seg fault when we return while opening file fails. Thanks for pointing this.